# Locating the project.parent's POM

Tags: inheritance, maven-2, dependency-management, circular-dependency

I'm using Maven in a project which contains a number of modules.  When we release, **we deploy the modules to our own Maven repository**.  The project modules inherit from a parent project which defines common properties such as reporting tools to be used, SCM location, repositories etc.

./pom.xml

```
<project>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <url>repo.example.com</url>
            ...
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    ...
</project>
```

./module/pom.xml

```
<project>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>module</artifactId>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>
    ...
</project>
```

It turns out there's an issue with this setup: when someone joins the project and tries to build a module, it will fail.  This is because `parent` **will not be available in their local Maven repository**, and cannot be fetched because `repo.example.com` **is only defined in the parent POM**.

Is there an obvious way round this problem, bar defining `<repositories/>` in every module's POM?

Answer (score 0):

In the `parent` section, add a `relativePath` element with content `..`.

```
<parent>
    ...
    <relativePath>..</relativePath>
</parent>
```

Comment: this should certainly work if parent and its POM have also been checked out.  Is this recommended?

Comment: @Alison I use it all the time. It keeps Maven from checking the repository if the relative path points to a parent POM with matching coordinates (you still need to provide the groupId, artifactId, and version of the parent).

Answer (score 0):

You should consider to deploy the parent `pom.xml` in your own Maven repository.

This way, even if the new developer does not have this parent on his machine, the first time he will try to compile one of your module project, Maven will download the parent `pom.xml` on his local repository, and then make it available for the module.

This should solve your problem.

Comment: we've deployed the parent to our repository, but our repository is not directly referenced in the child's POM.

Comment: @Alison Your repository could be defined in the developer `settings.xml` no?

Comment: yeah, although that's one more bit of config beyond "checking out the code" which I'd like to avoid

Answer (score 0):

RelativePath will work. However, I prefer to set the repository in settings.xml

Checking out the parent is overkill in my opinion, and you have to update the project when it changes.